# Selenium Chromedriver throws Service /opt/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium-webdriver, aws-lambda, selenium-chromedriver

I want to make web crawler with Python and Selenium.
I want to use AWS Lambdas.

I am using Python 3.11 and latest version of Selenium 4.18.1.

I am getting this error when I am running the lambda:

```
Response
{
  "statusCode": 500,
  "body": "Error: Message: Service /opt/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127\n"
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: e98db2ab-f047-4e5f-be4e-0705e0414108 Version: $LATEST
Extracting Bern courts news...
Message: Service /opt/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127
END RequestId: e98db2ab-f047-4e5f-be4e-0705e0414108
REPORT RequestId: e98db2ab-f047-4e5f-be4e-0705e0414108  Duration: 15.63 ms  Billed Duration: 16 ms  Memory Size: 3008 MB    Max Memory Used: 82 MB  Init Duration: 963.16 ms

Request ID
e98db2ab-f047-4e5f-be4e-0705e0414108
```

I have no idea why, I havent found anything on the web related to this.

I have installed all dependencies defined in requirements.txt:

```
requests==2.25.0
beautifulsoup4==4.8.0
boto3==1.34.62
urllib3==1.26.0
botocore==1.34.62
lambda_decorators==0.6.0
selenium==4.18.1
regex==2023.12.25
```

This is my code where I am calling selenium:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service


def get_headless_driver():
    options = Options()
    service = Service(executable_path=r'/opt/chromedriver')
    options.binary_location = '/opt/headless-chromium'
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--single-process')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_argument('--window-size=1920x1080')
    options.add_argument('--start-maximized')

    return webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)


def get_selenium_driver():
    return get_local_driver() if os.environ.get('STAGE') == 'local' else get_headless_driver()
```

Comment: Have you uploaded the code with all the libraries you need?

Comment: yes, I did. But my code breaks in the first line

Comment: you need to share some code or something

Comment: try setting permissions to execute the file with os.system('chmod 777 /opt/chromedriver'), if that doesn't work, copy the file to /tmp/ folder and give it permission to execute. Hopefully that will work.